# create a pie chart in vb.net in code

Tags: vb.net

i am new in reports in vb.net
i use v s 2008.
i want a simple help.
i want a hit or a Source Code or any Reference using that i can easily create a pie chart.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Microsoft Charting Controls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).